# calling functions for a password checker

Tags: python

this is my password checker code (whether it is valid or not)

I need to run the password checker for 5 times, until it's valid.
If it's valid, I have to break out of the loop.

The password should be more than 7 characters.
The password needs to include both numbers (at least two) and characters.
(If not, return False)
There should be no space.
If there is anything else than numbers and characters, I need to return False

I need to run my password_checker function in the for loop,
but I'm not so sure what to say after 'if'.

I have tried -

```
if a=False:
    print(password_checker(i))
    print(Invalid password)
```

but it didn't work.

Also, I don't understand how should I call my password_checker() in the for loop.

Finally, I need to put a break in my for loop
if the password in the input is valid.
But I'm not sure where is the appropriate part to place it

```
def password_checker(password):
    a=True
    num_Count = 0
    if password.isalpha() == True:
        print ("error! needs numbers")
        a = False

    if password.isnum() == True:
         print ("error! needs characters")
         a = False

    if password.isspace() == True:
         print ("error! no space allowed")
         a = False

    if len(password)<=8:
         print ("error! needs more than 8 characters")
        a = False

    for i in range(0, 10):
         num_Count += password.count(i)
    if num_Count(password.count()) < 2:
             print("error! needs at least 2 numbers")
            a = False


password = str(input("Enter password: "))

for i in range(0,5):
     if ____________________:
         print(password_checker(i))
         print("Invalid password")
    else:
        print(password_checker(i))
        print("Valid password")
        break
```

How should I correct my code in order to make my function work?

Comment: Hey, could you explain what you want to do, I dont understand why you are looping over numbers 0-4, when you actually receive the password only once. Try writing the flow in steps.

Comment: The first line of the code you posted already has a SyntaxError and won't run.

Comment: @Rohi Sorry, I added my explanations.

Comment: Why on earth do you want to loop 5 times over the exact same code with the exact same arguments, getting the exact same results ?

Comment: Also your password_checker function is totally broken.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
for i in range(0,5):
    password = str(input("Enter password: "))
    password_checker_result = password_checker(password)
    if not password_checker_result:
        print("Invalid password")
    else:
        print("Valid password")
        break
```

This code will work for you, now let me explain:

The flow is as following:

**This is done 5 times (is inside the for loop):**

1) Request password from user.

2) Check if password is valid.

3) Print according to valid/not valid result.

- The fact that you are using a for loop does not require you to actually use the iteration index (meaning 'i' in our case)

Comment: The OP's password_checker always return `None`

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers In his original question he asked not to look at the check password function and only help him with the loop.